# Create kubernetes resources with helm only if custom resource definition exists

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a helm chart that deploys a number of Kubernetes resources. One of them is a resource that is of a Custom Resource Definition (CRD) type (`ServiceMonitor` used by `prometheus-operator`).

I am looking for a way, how to "tell" helm that I'd want to create this resource only if such a CRD is defined in the cluster OR to ignore errors *only* caused by the fact that such a CRD is missing.

Is that possible and how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Helm's [Capabilities](https://v2.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/#built-in-objects) object can tell you if an entire API class is installed in the cluster.  I don't think it can test for a specific custom resource type.

In your `.tpl` files, you can wrap the entire file in a `{{ if }}...{{ end }}` block.  Helm doesn't especially care if the rendered version of a file is empty.

That would lead you to a file like:

```
{{ if .Capabilities.APIVersions.Has "monitoring.coreos.com/v1" -}}
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  ...
{{ end -}}
```

That would get installed if the operator is installed in the cluster, and skipped if not.

Answer (score 3):

If you are on Helm 3 you can put your CRD in the `crds/` directory. Helm will treat it differently, see the docs [here](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#custom-resource-definitions-crds).

In Helm 2 there is another mechanism using the crd-install hook. You can add the following to your CRD:

```
annotations:
  "helm.sh/hook": crd-install
```

There are some limitations with this approach so if you are using Helm 3 that would be preferred.

Comment: Thanks for your reseponse. I am using helm 2. About that helm hook, what is it going to do? Could you point me to some more info or docs? It looks to me that this will (somehow) try to install CRDs. I am looking for a bit different behavior

Comment: Ah did not realise you were actually not wrapping the CRD with your chart. I read the CRD type as actually having type: CustomResourceDefinition. My bad. crd-install indeed does not work then in this case. You could create a pre_install hook to check if the CRDs are installed and otherwise prevent the chart from being deployed (https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/). The other approach is to check for the CRD as part of a deployment script and pass a value to your helm chart whether the CRD exists or not (allowing silent ignores).

Answer (score 2):

In Helm v3, you can test for specific resources:

```yaml
{{ if .Capabilities.APIVersions.Has "monitoring.coreos.com/v1/ServiceMonitor" -}}
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  ...
spec:
  ...
{{- end }}
```

https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/builtin_objects/